# Why do some phrase with comma not create a nebensatz?

Tags: german-to-english, subordinate-clause

> (De)Ja, du hast das wohl gemacht.
>
> (Eng)Yeah, you did that well.

In German sentence, the second part is not actually a nebensatz. Why? Is it not so though the phrase is after a comma?

Comment: To be clear what is going on, the "yeah"/"*ja*" is just a word tacked on to the sentence; it doesn't affect the grammar of the rest of the sentence. I call it a preamble, though there are probably more "official" grammatical terms. Other examples in English include various interjections ("wow", "yuck", etc.) and a person's name if you're trying to get their attention. Similar words can be added to the end of a sentence as postambles. You can even have interambles: "I won't do that, Amy, because it's illegal."

Comment: For there to be a subordinate clause, there has to be a main clause. A single *Ja* does not count as a main clause.

Comment: Nebenpoint. I'm not a Muttersprachler, but I don't think "wohl" typically translates to "well" in its sense as the adverb form of "good". I think your sentence would more likely be interpreted as: "Yes, you probably did that."

Comment: @cruthers: You're right, or "Yes, it looks like you did that."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for something to constitute a clause, it is required to have a finite form of a verb. As there are a lot of scenarios where there is a comma, but not two finite verbs, not every comma creates a (subordinate) clause. Here are just a few constructions with a comma and no subordinate clause, this is not necessarily a complete list:

1. Some commas are just enumerations:

> Ich gehe zum Bäcker, nach Hause, und danach ins Büro.

2. Another common counterexample of your hypothesis is a paratactic structure, that is two main clauses connected by a conjunction. Conjunctions of *und*, *oder* and *denn* (and others probably, this is just off the top of my head) combine two main clauses:

> Ich gehe zum Bäcker und danach gehe ich nach Hause.
> Ich gehe zum Bäcker oder ich gehe ins Büro.
> Ich gehe zum Bäcker, denn ich habe Hunger.

There is a lot more on this, and I recommend you read a grammar introduction into main clauses and subordinate clauses in German. Maybe [[this](https://wortwuchs.net/grammatik/satzgefuege/)][1](https://wortwuchs.net/grammatik/satzgefuege/) could be a good start.

3. A third example is an apposition:

> Monika Meyer, unsere Direktorin, ist heute im Urlaub.

4. Another group (and this is the one in your example), is just an interjection:

> Ja, du hast das wohl gemacht.

*[Ja,]*  cannot be a clause, because it has no finite verb.

Comment: But could you explain how one knows if comma created a subordinate clause or not?

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational I added some explanation in the beginning. But I really recommend you take a look in a grammar book / website. :)

Comment: Whether a clause is a subclause or a main clause, can a) be identified by word order, or b) by knowing by heart those conjunctions introducing a main clause as well as those introducting a subordinate clause.